# php uploader invalid

Tags: php, uploader

I'm trying to embed file uploader but it's showing invalid error for pdf and other application files, following code i'm using, can anyone help me tracing out the error why its showing up invalid message. thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" );
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
  else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
    }
          }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: your indenting and nesting seems quite difficult to parse. I suggest you sort that out so maybe it would be easier to understand yourself what your code is doing. I suggest refactoring to separate functions/blocks and autoformatting the code.

Comment: One simple change such as caching `$_FILES['file']` will make that code so much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You allow only `.gif`, `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.png` on line 1:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" );
```

If you upload PDF, of course it will prompt `Invalid file`

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
   $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" )
```

Does not contain "pdf",Please add allowed extensions "$allowedExts" like

```
     $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","pdf","php" );
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

use: `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","pdf");`

instead of: `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" );`

And for future please keep in mind to add the extensions you want to allow for.

I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fault has been already pointed out.

In addition to that, if you refactor and reformat your code to something like

```
$allowedExts = Array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" );
$allowedContentTypes = Array("application/pdf", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif");
$fileSizeLimit = 50000;

function getExtension($file)
{
  return end(explode(".", $file["name"]));
}
function hasAllowedContentType($file)
{
  return in_array($file['type'], $allowedContentTypes);
}
function isWithinSizeLimits($file)
{
  return $file['size'] < $fileSizeLimit;
}
function hasAllowedExtension($file)
{
  $extension = getExtension($file['name');
  return in_array($extension, $allowedExts);
}
function alreadyExists($path)
{
  return file_exists($path);
}

$file = $_FILES["file"];
$targetPath = "upload/" . $file["name"];
$tempPath = $file["tmp_name"];

if (!hasAllowedContentType($file)
   || !isWithinSizeLimits($file)
   || !hasAllowedExtension($file))
{
   echo "Invalid file";
}
else if ($file["error"] > 0)
{
   printf("Return Code: %s<br>", $file["error"]);
}
else
{
  printf("Upload: %s<br>", $file["name"]);
  printf("Type: %s<br>", $file["type"]);
  printf("Size: %d kB<br>", ($file["size"] / 1024));
  printf("Temp file: %s<br>", $tempPath);

  if (alreadyExists($targetPath))
  {
    printf("%s already exists.", $file["name"]);
  }
  else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($tempPath, $targetPath);
    printf("Stored in: %s", $targetPath);
  }
}
```

it is already a lot easier to understand and maintain.